# Retrieve invoice details when retrieving invoices

Tags: c#, .net, linq, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-2016

I've got this simple LINQ to CRM query:

```
//retrieve all invoices associated to the cycle...
List<Invoice> invoiceCycleInvoices = ctx.InvoiceSet.Where(x => x.new_invoice_cycle_invoicesid.Id == invoiceCycle.Id
    && x.new_erpsync == false
    && x.StateCode != InvoiceState.Canceled).ToList();
```

Usually, a `ToList` call pulls all the relevant information that lazy loading forgets, but there is this property called `invoice_details` in `Invoice` that's always null.

How do I get it populated in one fell swoop ?

Comment: The `invoice_details` is a child?

Comment: Yes, sorry. Edited the question to clear that up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access entity relationships using [LoadProperty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg695791.aspx).

```
foreach (var invoice in invoiceCycleInvoices)
{
    ctx.LoadProperty(invoice, "invoice_details");
    var invoiceDetail = invoice.GetRelatedEntity<Entity>("invoice_details");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
List<Invoice> invoiceCycleInvoices = ctx.InvoiceSet
    .Where(x => x.new_invoice_cycle_invoicesid.Id == invoiceCycle.Id
        && x.new_erpsync == false
        && x.StateCode != InvoiceState.Canceled)
    .Include(x => x.invoice_details)
    .ToList();
```